# why multipy alpha componnet and green component which gets from texture

Tags: three.js, fragment-shader

I'm trying to figure out why threejs multipy alpha and green component:

```js
export default /* glsl */`
#ifdef USE_ALPHAMAP

    diffuseColor.a *= texture2D( alphaMap, vUv ).g;

#endif
`;
```

Thanks in advance!~

Comment: I find out the [basic reason](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshBasicMaterial.alphaMap) _the extra bit of precision provided for green_, but still unclear about the real reason.

Comment: There's no point in adding the tags to the title of the question

Comment: There is no other reason. The documentation exactly states why the green channel is sampled.